# If $Γ,A \vDash B$ and $Γ,A \vDash \lnot B$, then $Γ \vDash \lnot A$

Tags: propositional-calculus

The task is to show that for every set Γ of propositions:

If $Γ,A \vDash B$ and $Γ,A \vDash \lnot B$, then $Γ \vDash \lnot A$.

This follows Gallier's notation and is actually taken right out of his book.

However, I have trouble showing this. I cannot see any case for which both premises on the left to be true, the right side would also be true. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction.

Assume not, i.e. $\Gamma \nvDash \lnot A$. This means that there is a *valuation* $v$ such that $v(\gamma_i)=$**t**, for every $\gamma_i \in \Gamma$ and $v(\lnot A)=$**f**.

Thus, for this valuation $v$ we have :

> $v(\gamma_i)=$**t**, for every $\gamma_i \in \Gamma$, and $v(A)=$**t**.

We know that $\Gamma, A \vDash B$, and thus (because it reads : "if for all *valuations* ..."; see [**Def.3.3.4**, page 42](https://books.google.it/books?id=6VV1CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA42)) we have $v(B)=$**t**.

We know also that $\Gamma, A \vDash \lnot B$, and thus $v(\lnot B)=$**t**.

Thus, we have a valuation $v$ such that :

> $v(B)=v(\lnot B)=$**t**,

*contradiction* !

Comment: Your solution is logical, yet pardon me for asking, but isn't the statement still inconclusive if we assume that Γ⊨¬A holds?

Comment: @Marcel - we have to prove that $\Gamma \vDash \lnot A$ holds; thus, we cannot assume it !